# Why wouldn't this work for a hashtable in C (pointers)

Tags: c, pointers, hashtable

The goal is to allow a hashtable in C to handle complex keys like structs or strings.

```
    char *key="hello";
    struct stuff value;
    /*initialize value */
    hashtable_put ((int)key, (int&value));
    struct stuff *p = (struct stuff *)hashtable_get((int)"hello");
    assert((*p)==value);
```

The solution that I have been provided is that it wouldn't work because comparing and hashing keys and pointers are not the same. To make this work, you'd have to pass a key comparison and key hashing function to hashtable_create(). Can someone explain why that is?

Comment: Just because the content of `key` equals "hello" doesn't mean `(int) key` and `(int) "hello"` are equal, that's not how pointers work. Consider using a hashing function that always returns the same value for the same string.

Comment: For one, the premise of a "hash key" in your lingo is apparently flawed. A hash **index** is generated by a hash **function** that takes a piece of key data and turns it into something of the index type. Casting a pointer to `int` isn't the way to do that for you hash table You need a function that takes a key (a string) and returns a `int` (the index). (side note: though in this case it demonstrates nicely that you're *not* compiling your code with "merge duplicate strings" turned on as an optimization).

Answer (score 1):

Pointer only points location in memory. Location is represented as an address, integer value, number of byte in memory. It doesn't carry any other information. Wheh you create a string with `char *key="hello";`, you are getting a place in memory where this text is placed, and a pointer to this location. When you create two strings,

```
char *key_a="hello";
char *key_b="hello";
```

You will get two diffrent locations, two diffrent integer values, but, still the same text.
So, you can not use this value as key, because two diffrent addreses can hold the same value.

Comment: Correct, complementing the answer, the hash must be calculated from the value's contents, not its address.

Comment: Correct in general, though with this specific example, the compiler may optimize it by commoning the strings (making the pointers the same)...

Comment: That's true, but usually hashes, or dictionaries in general, are used with strings built in real time.